# Splitting up mp4 files with ffmpeg results in black videos

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, quicktime

I'm trying to split a long video in mp4 format into 60 second sections:

```
ffmpeg -i YDXJ0028.mp4 -c copy -segment_time 60 -f segment YDXJ0028_%03d.mp4
```

This kind produces the segmented video files, but depending on the player they show various problems:

- VLC: The first segement plays fine. For all other segments the timebar is not working.
- Quicktime: The first segement plays fine. For all other segments the screen remains black.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i YDXJ0028.mp4 -c copy -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment YDXJ0028_%03d.mp4
```

This makes each segment start with timestamp 0. Safe for broad compatibility.

Comment: Works Perfec! For Quicktime and VLC.

Comment: "-reset_timestamps 1" fixed my issue where all videos after the first had a broken seek bar in VLC because they were utilizing the first videos timestamp. Thanks

Comment: Works Great!!!
Thanks so much!